# Git: How to find out if fetching from a remote updated my submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

We have a standard workflow, where the local git workspace gets updated from a remote in a standard way at regular intervals. This will merge into master and it will also make sure the existing submodules are made up to date if necessary and that any new submodules will get initialized and pulled too. 
Part of that update step is then a re-build process for submodulues in a specific location that have been changed or added.
My question is now: apart from checking the actual locations, is there an easy way to find out if submodules have changed or were added? For example is there a documented exit code of git submodule update which would tell me what happened? Is there some other standard way to do this - I am pretty sure something like that must be needed in many projects?  Also, what is the best way to check if the git pull or git fetch and merge commands have changed anything?